# Trying to use angular-auto-validate by jonsamwell, but form validation is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Here is the JS code, every thing work fine except the form is not validated.

```
var app = angular.module('minmax', ['jcs-autoValidate']);

app.controller('MinMaxCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
$scope.formModel = {};
$scope.onSubmit = function(valid){

    if(valid){

        console.log("form submitted");
        console.log($scope.formModel);


    }else{
        console.log("invalid form");
    }
};
}]);
```

Here is my HTML page, there's a form in here that i want to validate using the angular auto validate.
Every thing work fine except the form is not validated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us" ng-app="minmax">
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<head>

   <title>AngularJS weathre Forecast SPA</title>   
   <Meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <style>

        html, body, input, select, textarea
        {
            font-size: 1.05em !important;
        }

    </style>

    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jonsamwell/angular-auto-validate/master/dist/jcs-auto-validate.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js.js"></script>

</head>
<body >


    <div class="container main-content" ng-controller="MinMaxCtrl">

        <form ng-submit="onSubmit(theForm.$valid)" name="theForm" novalidate>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="formModel.name" name="name" required/>
            </div>

         <!--   

//////////////////////////////////////// Form validation with core angularJS ///////////////////////////////////////

            <div class="form-group "
                 ng-class="{
                     'has-error': !theForm.email.$valid && (!theForm.$pristine || theForm.$submitted),
                     'has-success': theForm.email.$valid && (!theForm.$pristine || theForm.$submitted)
                 }">
                <label>Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" ng-model="formModel.email" required/>

                <p class="help-block" ng-show="theForm.email.$error.required && (!theForm.$pristine || theForm.$submitted)" >
                    This field is required.
                </p>

                <p class="help-block" ng-show="theForm.email.$error.email && (!theForm.$pristine || theForm.$submitted)" >
                    Please enter an email id.
                </p>

                <pre>Validation {{theForm.email.$error | json}}</pre>
                <pre>Field Valid? {{theForm.email.$valid}}</pre>
                <pre>Form pristine? {{theForm.$pristine}}</pre>
                <pre>Form Submitted? {{theForm.$submitted}}</pre>
            </div>-->

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" ng-model="formModel.email" required/>

            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" ng-model="formModel.password" required/>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Age</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="Age" ng-model="formModel.age" required/>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="sex">Sex</label>
                <select name="sex" id="sex" class="form-control" ng-model="formModel.sex" required>
                    <option value="" > Please choose </option>
                    <option value="Male" > Male </option>
                    <option value="Female" > Female </option>
                </select>
            </div>



            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Register</button>
            </div>

        </form>
    <pre>{{theForm | json}}</pre>

    </div>


</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that all you have is working well.

See example [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/qysm3b55/).

Is that, I did not use the module `jcs-autoValidate`